# SAP WEBI API json call for schedule report with prompt

Tags: webi

I can't find format for JSON call to schedule reports with prompts.

tried to use  `/biprws/v1/documents/"docID"/parameters` to get prompts but it returns an error:

> "message": "Error while performing the request; server is unable to find the match for the Request-URI (RWS 00056)"

I need help to add prompts params "Select An As Of Date" to my JSON request:

```
{
    "retriesallowed": 0,
    "retryintervalinseconds": 1800
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for more information I found that there are 2 address for calls

The base URL is http://:6405/biprws and 2nd one is http://:6405/biprws/raylight/v1

[More info on SAP web page](https://help.sap.com/viewer/58f583a7643e48cf944cf554eb961f5b/4.2/en-US/63071d555f7c481f9bdae1fc7aececd0.html)